# Zip and Zip Longest

Tags: python

I am trying to use the `zip()` and `itertools.zip_longest()` function. I need help understand them and maybe fix the error i am getting. With `zip()` the code runs, but it doesnt get all the entries in one of those lists. With `itertools.zip_longest()` i am getting an error that i couldn't figure it out.

This is my code (Running it through Google Colab):

```
!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/muriloasouza/Deep-Learning/master/Input.txt
!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/muriloasouza/Deep-Learning/master/Labels.txt
!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/muriloasouza/Deep-Learning/master/Input_Train.txt
!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/muriloasouza/Deep-Learning/master/Labels_Train.txt
!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/muriloasouza/Deep-Learning/master/Input_Valid.txt
!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/muriloasouza/Deep-Learning/master/Labels_Valid.txt

batch_size = 3
df_input_train=pd.read_csv('./Input_Train.txt',usecols =['Wind_MWh','Actual_Load_MWh'],chunksize = 24*batch_size, iterator=True)
df_target_train=pd.read_csv('./Labels_Train.txt',usecols =['Potencia_Media_do_Vento_(MW)','Desvio_Padrao_Vento_(MW)','FCSPV_(Fracao_de_Carga_Suprida_pela_Potencia_do_Vento)'],chunksize = batch_size, iterator=True)
df_input_valid=pd.read_csv('./Input_Valid.txt',usecols =['Wind_MWh','Actual_Load_MWh'],chunksize = 24*batch_size, iterator=True)
df_target_valid=pd.read_csv('./Labels_Valid.txt',usecols =['Potencia_Media_do_Vento_(MW)','Desvio_Padrao_Vento_(MW)','FCSPV_(Fracao_de_Carga_Suprida_pela_Potencia_do_Vento)'],chunksize = batch_size, iterator=True)
c= 0 
for chunk, chunk2, chunk3, chunk4 in itertools.zip_longest(df_input_train,df_target_train,df_input_valid,df_target_valid):
  c = c+1
  X_train = chunk.values
  X_valid = chunk3.values
  X_train = np.resize(X_train,(batch_size,24,2,1))
  X_valid = np.resize(X_valid,(batch_size,24,2,1))
  Y_train = chunk2.values
  Y_valid = chunk4.values
print(X_train)
print(c)
```

And the error:

```
     17   c = c+1
     18   X_train = chunk.values
---> 19   X_valid = chunk3.values
     20   X_train = np.resize(X_train,(batch_size,24,2,1))
     21   X_valid = np.resize(X_valid,(batch_size,24,2,1))

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'values'
```

**1:** `zip()` iterates over the smallest list passed (thats the reason its missing some entries in one of those lists)?

**2:** `zip_longest()` iterates over the greater one?

**3:** Why i am getting that error?

**4:** Is there anyway i can iterate in each list over exactly it's length?

Comment: Have you read the docs for `zip_longest`? It would cover this.

Comment: What would you want to happen with the missing items when one list is shorter than the others?

Comment: Have you tried `izip`?

Comment: I couldn't find `zip_longest` being used anywhere? Try reading the [documentation](https://realpython.com/python-itertools/) of itertools. It should give you a complete understanding of `zip_longest`.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] (i.e. one not using `numpy` and `dataframe`s).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

zip combines multiple iterators.

For a quick example, run:

```py
for x in zip(range(10),range(5)):
    print(x)
```

This only prints 5 times because zip ends at the shortest iterator.

`zip_longest()` will go through all entries, and if one of the iterators runs out early, it gets replaced with `None`.

```py
import itertools
for x in itertools.zip_longest(range(10),range(5)):
    print(x)
```

**1.**
Yes, `zip()` iterates up to the length of the shortest iterator.

**2.**
Yes, `zip_longest()` iterates up to the length of the longest iterator.

**3.**
You are getting that error because chunk3 is shorter than the longest iterator, so at that iteration, its value is `None`. None doesn't have a `values` attribute.

**4.**
Right now you are iterating them all together. It doesn't really make sense to ask if you can only iterate for each ones length since they have different lengths and you are iterating together. Either you miss some values or you have `None` values for some iterations. If you don't need the values together, you could look at something like itertools chain.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anyway i can iterate in each list over exactly it's length?

From the `itertools.zip_longest` docstring:

> When the shorter iterables are exhausted, the `fillvalue` is substituted
>   in their place. The `fillvalue` defaults to None or can be specified by
>   a keyword argument.

```
>>> for a, b in itertools.zip_longest([1, 2, 3, 4], "abcdefghijk"):
    print(a, b)


1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
None e
None f
None g
None h
None i
None j
None k
```

Using explicit `fillvalue`:

```
for a, b in itertools.zip_longest([1, 2, 3, 4], "abcdefghijk", fillvalue="YAY"):
    print(a, b)


1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
YAY e
YAY f
YAY g
YAY h
YAY i
YAY j
YAY k
```

You'll have to decide what should happen when an item is missing.